# State Abbreviation Codes in Visual Basic 2010 Express

Tags: vb.net

Am really glad i get someone to help with this , but the problem is am not really good on vb as am very new to it , can anyone please arrange it for me as it need to be then i will see what i can do with it . Then i will be able to start the project

Question is to change states name to 2 Letter and calculate tax rate for them as well.
California retail customers (State code = “CA”) are charged a sales tax on purchases – the California tax rate is 10%. Retail customers from New York (state code = “NY”) and Florida (state code = “FL”) are also taxed at a 5% tax rate.

Below is the code i have so far

```
Public Class Form1

Public Class State
  Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal abbr As String, ByVal taxPercent As Decimal)
    Me.Name = name
    Me.Abbreviation = abbr
    Me.TaxPercent = taxPercent
  End Sub

  Public Property Name As String
  Public Property Abbreviation As String
  Public Property TaxPercent As Decimal
End Class

Const U_P_S_DECIMAL As Decimal = 7D

Const SALES_TAX_RATE_SINGLE As Single = 0.1 '10 Percent Rate

'declare module-level variables
Private TotalQuantityInteger As Integer
Private TotalSalesDecimal As Decimal

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Try
    '5 percent salses tex rate
    Const SALES_TEX_RATE_SINGLE As Single = 0.05 '5 percent rate


    Dim states As New List(Of State)
    states.Add(New State("California", "CA", 10))
    states.Add(New State("New York", "NY", 5))
    states.Add(New State("Florida", "FL", 5))

    For Each state As State In states
        Console.WriteLine("State: {0} Abbrevation: {1} Tax: {2}%",
                          state.Name, state.Abbreviation, state.TaxPercent)
    Next

    'Declare variables
    Dim SubDecimal, SalesTaxDecimal, TotalDueDecimal, TotalCostDecimal, ShippingCostDecimal As Decimal
    'Declare variables and convert value from textbox controls to memory
    Dim PriceDecimal As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(PriceTextBox.Text, Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency)
    Dim QuantityInteger As Integer = Integer.Parse(QuantityTextBox.Text, Globalization.NumberStyles.Number)

    'Process - Compute values
    'Subtotal = price times the quantity of books
    TotalCostDecimal = PriceDecimal * QuantityInteger

    'Sales tex = sales tax rate times the subtotal minus discount amount
    SalesTaxDecimal = Decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(TotalCostDecimal * SALES_TEX_RATE_SINGLE), 2)

    SubDecimal = SalesTaxDecimal + ShippingCostDecimal

    'Total due is the subtotal minus discount amount plus sales tex
    TotalDueDecimal = TotalCostDecimal + SubDecimal

    If UPSRadioButton.Checked Then 'compute the shipping cost
        ShippingCostDecimal = U_P_S_DECIMAL * QuantityInteger
    End If


    'Output - display output formatted as currency
    SubtotalTextBox.Text = TotalCostDecimal.ToString("C")
    TotalDueTextBox.Text = TotalDueDecimal.ToString("C")
    salestaxTextBox.Text = SalesTaxDecimal.ToString("N")
    ShippingCostTextBox.Text = ShippingCostDecimal.ToString("N")

    'Accumulate total sales and total books sold
    TotalQuantityInteger += QuantityInteger
    TotalSalesDecimal += TotalDueDecimal
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
End Sub
```

I have input the code i got on here but i dont know what to do to collect the data from textbox when the state is entered so that tax can be added to it . Any help will be appreciated. Am new to VB so i dont really know how everything works

Comment: you already have a state class and a List(of state), so rather than a textbox, use a Combo for the state.  Use the List<state> as the datasource.  WHen they pick a state the selectditem will have the name, 2 letter and tax rate you can use elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For Each state As State In states
    If state.name = TextBox.text then
    'add your code here, you get the tax Rate with state.TaxPercent
    '...
    exit for
Next
```